# Problema com instalação de bibliotecas no Delphi XE8

Tags: delphi, instalador, biblioteca

Estava tentando instalar as bibliotecas ID3v1 e ID3v2, mas quando fui instalar houve um erro porque essas bibliotecas utilizam units como TntClasses, TntSysUtils, etc. Então procurei na internet e encontrei o Tnt Unicode Controls.
Então baixei, abri o arquivo *.dpk mas quando tento compilar ele da erro porque no 'requires' tem o package 'vcl'.

Então ele da a seguinte mensagem de erro.

> TntUnicodeVcl.dpk : E2202 Required package 'vcl' not found.

Não achei nada que resolve-se meu problema na internet. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Será que tentei instalar de forma errada ou algo do tipo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro geralmente ocorre quando há problemas na instalação do Delphi. Cheque no Library Path (Tools > Options > Delphi Options > Library) se ele possui os caminhos default (estão na pasta do Delphi, subpastas):

\lib\Win32\release,  \Imports,  \Dcp,  \include

Ou reinstale o Delphi (maioria dos casos só resolve reinstalando)

Answer (score 1):

Parece que o componente não é compatível com a versão XE8 e não consegue encontrar o diretorio  que contém a VCL. Verifique isto.
Se for o componente da 3DeLite's, segundo o site deles o componente  é compatível até o XE5.

Comment: Hmm.... Pois é, eu até consegui corrigir o erro do vcl, procurei na pasta do Delphi esses arquivos que eu precisava (vcl.dcp, vclx.dcp) e copiei eles pra mesma pasta da biblioteca que estou tentando instalar, e o erro sumiu, mas agora ocorre o seguinte erro:

F2051 Unit System was compiled with a different version of "".@DelayLoadHelper2

Comment: Tente recompilar o package. Pode ser que funcione.